# To simplify similar language metadata for itunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect, fastlane, fastlane-deliver

itunes-connect has some similar languages like en-US, en-UK,en-AU

I would like to use the same screenshots and descriptions for these languages.

For now, I made each folder for this kind of similar languages.

For example

```
metadata/
en-US
en-UK(copy from en-US)
en-AU(copy from en-AU)

screenshots/
en-US
en-UK(copy from en-US)
en-AU(copy from en-AU)
```

However it is a bit redundant and awkward.

Is there any work around way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use different screenshots/metadata, why do you need localizations in the first place?

Example: If you only have "en-US" as language, all other stores/languages will fallback to "en-US", so there is no need to activate the other languages.

---

**Back to the original question:**

Apple introduced the "Media Manager" some time ago. It allows you to re-use the primary language's screenshots for other locales. You can also upload only the highest resolution screenshots (5.5inch & 12.9inch) and let Apple scale them appropriately for smaller devices.

With regards to metadata (description, URLs, keywords etc.) there is no wait to automatically copy over the information in iTunes Connect. Even though if you add a new language it will automatically copy over the **current** (!) values of the primary locale. Shameless plug here: Use 3rd party tools like [Transporter](https://transporterapp.io) (UI). For Fastlane you just have to copy & paste the information. There is currently no plugin or action that does that for you.